# How to add `c8y_Address` property to a device using API in cumulocity?

Tags: cumulocity

[Here is the image of the asset information widget, which can add a property called `c8y_Address`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRnBM.png)

I would like my device to show their address information on the asset information widget, but I don't really know how to upload these properties to a device.

I am using MQTT. So I created a customised SMQRT Template, which is a POST inventory method `001,<region>,<street>,<territory>`. And then I publish it using `client.publish('s/uc/TemplateName',`001,${region},${address},${territory}`);`. But it doesn't work.

I'm just wondering how can we use API to add the address information as a property of a device?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

POST would create a new object. I guess what you want to do is updating the device with this properties. So a PUT template would be the correct choice.

[image]

Note that the preview shown in the UI currently is incorrect for PUT templates.

It says:

```
999,<c8y_Address.region>,<c8y_Address.street>,<c8y_Address.territory>
```

but it actually needs to be (like described in the SmartREST 2.0 guide):

```
999,<externalId>,<c8y_Address.region>,<c8y_Address.street>,<c8y_Address.territory>
```

The externalId needs to be from the device you want to update (if you only have a single device without children it would be what you also use as MQTT clientId).